# equivalent of `grep -a /dev/sda1` on Darwin?

Tags: osx, hard-disk, devices

I want to run something like

```
% sudo grep -i -a 'some-string' <drive device>
```

On Linux, `<drive device>` would be something like `/dev/sda1`.  How can I find the equivalent on Darwin?

(In case it's not obvious, I'm on a last-ditch-effort hunt for accidentally deleted data.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the filesystem takes over the whole disk, OS X currently uses a name like `/dev/disk5`. If the disk is partitioned, it adds an `s#` suffix, like `/dev/disk5s2` for the second partition. (`s` is short for "slice," a BSDism functionally equivalent to a partition.)

Disks are numbered sequentially in discovery order by the OS, on boot, so you may have to experiment a bit to figure out which device is which.

If you say `diskutil list` at the command line, you get a detailed list of available disks, including their `/dev` nodes and volume names:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   ...etc..
/dev/disk7
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Time Machine           *999.5 GB   disk7
```

In the case of `disk0` above, there are three slices on the disk, so there is a `/dev/disk0` for the whole disk, plus `/dev/disk0s1` through `...s3`.

In the case of `disk7`, there are no slices reported, so you would access that one through the whole-disk `/dev/disk7` node.

Comment: trying to do this on mac and I get the following error `/dev/disk1: Operation not permitted`.  I've tried sudo and I've tried switching to root via `sudo su` no luck.  Wondering if I need to unmount the disk, but I'm worried that may be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

When `grep`ping a disk - unless you're actually looking for non-printable information - you might like to do:

```
tr -c '[:print:]\n' '\n\n' </dev/disk |
grep -b 'regex'
```

All binary data is converted to newlines and `grep` can simply ignore it except to increment the offset it reports on by one.

Comment: It's a neat trick, but it doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - very true. More useful as an aside. I honestly don't know how Apple does it, and don't expect it to be accepted or even upvoted. It's just... help, you know?

Comment: @WarrenYoung - by the way - if you wanted to put it in your answer, *which does answer the question*, I'd happily delete this.

Comment: Better idea: ask a question to which this *is* the answer. Then you get points for being clever. :)

Answer (score -1):

I noticed a few gotchas when grepping disk devices which I noted here with a helper script:

http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/disk_grep.html